# JMeter: I have to run scenario where I am loading the api

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, application-software-testing

I have to start with 100 users and keep increasing them gradually until they reach 1000 and I have to run it for some duration.

I am trying threads as 1000 and ramp up as 10 that means 100 users will hit in 1st second and 200 in another and so on.

I am not sure on:

1. How to run it for particular duration?
2. After that reaches 1000 users would it become stable like the load will be for 1000 users only?

I want the thread to start with 100 users and 200, 300 then reach 1000. How could I achieve that? Currently with number of threads= 1000 and ramp up of 10 I see it starts with 0 and reaches 1000 instantly .
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. You can specify your test desired duration via "Duration (seconds)" input of the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

   [image]
2. If you want to have "stable" load of 1000 concurrent users after the ramp-up time make sure to tick "Infinite" box next to "Loop Count"

   [image]

You can observe how many virtual users were online in this or that period of your test execution using [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/))

[image]